# Python if else statement based on sign

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried to transform a list of numbers into the list of the signs of the numbers from this list, while i have so many option to do so, I found a weird response from python3:

```
a =[0.5]
for x in a:
    if x > 0:
        print('sup 0')
    if x < 0:
        print('inf 0')
    else:
        print('egal 0')
```

output:
sup 0
egal 0

Can someone explain me why this output occur ?

Best regards

Comment: It runs both if statements and the second one will always have one of the outcomes. You need to use elif, if you want all of the checks to be made. `if x > 0 elif x < 0 else`

Comment: use `if ... elif ... else` instead of `if ... if ... else`

Comment: Note that even in the fixed code, the `egal 0` option may or may not happen when expected, for example for `0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` you'll get `sup 0` because it's not quite zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) here if you want exactly one of possibilities, i.e. do

```
a =[0.5]
for x in a:
    if x > 0:
        print('sup 0')
    elif x < 0:
        print('inf 0')
    else:
        print('egal 0')
```

You can have zero or more `elif` parts, `else` is optional. This is `python`'s equivalent of `switch`...`case` found in some other programming languages, e.g. `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you run the first if, which is true then the second if which is false and hence giving the else as answer.

Try it like this, this should work as expected.

```
a =[0.5]
for x in a:
    if x > 0:
        print('sup 0')
    elif x < 0:
        print('inf 0')
    else:
        print('egal 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use elif

```
a =[0.5]
for x in a:
    if x > 0:
        print('sup 0')
    elif x < 0:
        print('inf 0')
    else:
        print('egal 0')
```